# Local page links for non-indexed methods

Tags: c++, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm using sphinx to document a C++ project, in which there are various pages that document a class.  In these I've used `:noindex:` for the class methods, since otherwise they clutter the whole project Index page.

```
.. cpp:function:: void foo(int a)
    :noindex:
```

However, one of the differences this also makes is that I cannot create local in-page links.  Eg., in the doc body for a different method:

```
The first argument is the same as that to :cpp:func:`foo`.
```

Without `:noindex:` on `foo()`, this link works.  With it, no error is generated and there is a link, but it's dead/useless/goes nowhere.

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manual creation of local links is fairly simple in reStructuredText:

```
.. _`foo()`
.. cpp:function:: void foo(int a)
    :noindex:
```

Defines the target without changing the appearance of anything. To link it,

```
The first argument is the same as that to `foo()`_.
```

Notice the location of the underscore is front to back.  The ticks are needed if you want to include the parentheses; if the label is plain alphanumeric they can be discarded.

A few shortcomings:

- You can't wrap this in mark-up, eg., to monospace or emphasize the link text.
- There doesn't seem to be a way to substitute the link text.